# express routes not working - returning 404 error

Tags: express

I'm trying to set up a simple express project, and backend will be purely for api and frontend will be vue. I tried adding an api router, and not only does it not work, but even the root page doesn't work. I've not coded in express for a very long time, and wondering if some one could guide me on what's the problem? The error message is `404 NotFoundError: Not Found`.

I'm navigating to localhost:3000, and I can see the call on the terminal, so port should be correct too?

```
/src/api/urls.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Just a test');
});

module.exports = router;
```

I didn't change the folder structure/naming for the original routes/index.js.

```
/src/routes/index.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Just a test');
});

module.exports = router;
```

And for the main file

```
/src/app.js
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var apiRouter = require('./api/urls');

var app = express();

app.use(require('connect-history-api-fallback')());

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/api', apiRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score -1):

All good except endpoint url that should be with middleware function only. Modifying these should work,

```
/src/api/urls.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


router.get('/api/test', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Just a test');
});

module.exports = router;


/src/routes/index.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


router.get('/api/test2', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Just a test');
});

module.exports = router;
```

In `app.js` you should register your routes as,

```
// Routes
app.use([
  require('./src/api/urls'),
  require('./src/routes/index'),
]);
```

Access by url ( `http://<yourhost>/api/test1` )